# Keep Rails from redirecting a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm having some trouble and I hope someone can help me. I have an erb file with a form in it that has a button. When you click the button it redirects the page elsewhere and shows the erb file that I told it to point to. This is great except I'd really like to stuff the content of that directed-to erb file into a div that is sitting below my form. My view looks something like this.

```
<div id="formentry">
  <%= form_for @time, :url => {:action => 'list'}, :remote => true, :update => 'results' do |f|%>
  <%= select :time, :period, TimeSelectModel::TIMEVALUES %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```

From what I've read online this seems like the approach you're supposed to take to do this in Rails3 but I'm not finding that it's working. (see: the page is completely redirecting) What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Post the controller action that's handling this please.

Answer (score 1):

My impression from your post is that you want to submit a form and show the results without leaving the page.  What you are looking to do requires use of javascript/ajax.

Checkout railscast 205 for an example of how to do this.